# Spring Kafka - Consumer, container and listener

Tags: apache-kafka

What exactly are those classes? I'm reading about it all the day and cannot make any sense out of it. How exactly it connects to the logical Kafka consumer?

What exactly is the logical consumer which can consume from one partition(Is it the KafkaListener?). If I want to create multiple consumers what shall I do, should I create more @KafkaListeners. Do I need to specify @KafkaListener for each partition. Or can I solve it somehow by using ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer? Or should I start the whole context multiple times?

I completely don't get it.

Comment: Hello Zveratko, I'm having same problem. Can you please let me know what exactly these classes are doing and how they are used to as performance perspective. Thanks & Regards

Answer (score 0):

If you when use default option and  'KafkaListenenr'   annotation,  it will running One KafkaConsumer
But, You use ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer and concurrency property  greater than topic's partition size, it will running multiple consumer

If you set concurrency, create a KafkaMessageListenerContainer with a Consumer of that size. (  https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-kafka/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/main/java/org/springframework/kafka/listener/ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer.java#L149 )

reference : https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/reference/htmlsingle/#_concurrentmessagelistenercontainer

Comment: So running of three instances of i.e. Spring boot app, with one @KafkaListener is equivalent of running one such up with ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer and concurrency set to 3?

Comment: Yes, It is  kafka consumer group with 3 instances.

Comment: What is exactly the reason '   @KafkaListener(topics = "${message.topic.name}", group = "bar", containerFactory = "barKafkaListenerContainerFactory")' for defining group and also container factory [as done here](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/master/spring-kafka/src/main/java/com/baeldung/spring/kafka/KafkaApplication.java).Why not just specify topic?